# PHP - Dynamic Image Generation

Tags: php, image, dynamic, gd, php-gd

How do I create dynamic images using php which depend of `$_GET['x']` variables?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-request site. Have you attempted to write anything? You need [GD](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), basic graphic art skill, and basic programming skills to pull this off.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of that, but I don't know who to ask. I'm in a desperate need of this. I haven't tried anything, because I don't code php.

Comment: If you aren't going to code it yourself, I suggest contacting a freelancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest this library http://codecanyon.net/item/image-tools-with-bmp-support/239941 I've used it in a few projects I've worked on involving essentially your same needs. We needed a way to generate forum signatures dynamically based on data from the forum database such as the users name, profile picture, how many posts they had, etc.

Edit: Not sure if I'm allowed to advertise (I don't think I am) but if you have questions send me an email at peter at olds dot co.